# Is there a special quantity for direction?

Tags: vectors

As in, since vectors have magnitude and direction. And scalars have only magnitude, is there a special quantity for direction?

Comment: Are you familiar with the representation of vectors with components?

Comment: I am not. Are you referring to the parts of a vector?

Comment: Taking two dimensions as an example, $x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}$ has components $x,\,y$. But for all I know, by "parts" you mean $x\hat{i},\,y\hat{j}$.

Comment: What do you mean by quantity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent a vector as
$$\mathbf{v}=v\ \hat{v}$$
where $v$ is the magnitude of the vector (that is the length of the arrow if you like) and $\hat{v}$ is the unit along the vector $\mathbf{v}$. You can refer to the former as magnitude and later as the direction of a vector.

---

For example: In
$$\mathbf{v}=2\hat{i}$$
$2$ is the magnitude of the  vector while $\hat{i}$ is the direction of vector.